# Cannot install requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-requests

I tried to install the `requests` module by using `pip install requests`, but I got the `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` all the time.

I'm using Python 3 for Windows.

I've tried on other syntax like `py -m pip install requests` or `apt-get install python3-requests` but the problem has persisted.

```
File "<ipython-input-163-38059570e01a>", line 2
    pip3 install requests
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You need to do this at the command prompt, not while using Python.

Comment: `apt-get` is for linux btw

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Answer (score 0):

1. Launch windows command line as administrator
2. type:  pip3 install requests
3. press 'Enter'
4. Vote this post as the answer!

Comment: Fresh install of python 3.x on Windows won't discriminate between using the command "pip" or the command "pip3"

Comment: they might have python 2 too though

Comment: Good point, but from the look of the post, they just now installed python. :)  So I will edit my comment.

Comment: It works with !pip install requests